# Uncaught ReferenceError: Cannot access XXX before initialization ( vitejs & react )

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-context, vite

I use vite and reactjs , when i change something in code , i don 't see the change , i see only page refrech and render nothing ( white page ) and  error in console

```
helpers.ts:111 Uncaught ReferenceError: Cannot access 'ConnectedContext' before initialization
    at SignIn (index.tsx:54)
    at renderWithHooks (react-dom.development.js:14803)
    at updateFunctionComponent (react-dom.development.js:17034)
    at beginWork (react-dom.development.js:18610)
    at HTMLUnknownElement.callCallback2 (react-dom.development.js:188)
    at HTMLUnknownElement.sentryWrapped (helpers.ts:87)
    at Object.invokeGuardedCallbackDev (react-dom.development.js:237)
    at invokeGuardedCallback (react-dom.development.js:292)
    at beginWork$1 (react-dom.development.js:23203)
    at performUnitOfWork (react-dom.development.js:22154)
    at workLoopSync (react-dom.development.js:22130)
    at performSyncWorkOnRoot (react-dom.development.js:21756)
    at react-dom.development.js:11089
    at unstable_runWithPriority (scheduler.development.js:653)
```

Any help ?

Answer (score 4):

With high probability, you have a circular dependency between your imported modules.

See [here](https://github.com/vitejs/vite/issues/4430) the explanation.